# Elegant solution to find a pair of Strings in a List

Tags: java, strings

I'm new to Java8 and I must find an elegant solution to a problem. The problem goes I have a List of letters (of any size) that could contain any letter such as "A", "B", "C", "D", etc. I must check if I have an pair of "A" and "B". So, if I have something like ["A", "A", "C", "Z"], since I don't have both "A" and "B" the code should throw an error. I need to refactor something like this in java8...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class atest {

    public static void checkForABPair(List<String> letters) {
        int iA = 0;
        int iB = 0;
        for (String letter : letters) {
            if (letter.equals("A")) {
                iA = 1;
            }
            if (letter.equals("B")) {
                iB = 1;
            }
        }
        if ((1 == iA || 1 == iB) && (1 != iA || 1 != iB)) {
            System.out.println(letters + " - ERROR! The pair of letters [A - B] must be present at least once, or not at all!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(letters + " - Everything fine!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> letters = Arrays.asList("B", "A", "C");
        checkForABPair(letters);

        letters = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "C");
        checkForABPair(letters);

        letters = Arrays.asList("M", "S", "C");
        checkForABPair(letters);
    }
}
```

This must return the following:

```
[B, A, C] - Everything fine!
[A, A, C] - ERROR! The pair of letters [A - B] must be present at least once, or not at all!
[M, S, C] - Everything fine!
```

I need it done in a more elegant way. Anyone have a more elegant solution? Thanks!

Comment: For clarification: Does the list `["A", "C", "B"]` contain a pair of A and B?

Comment: yes, it has one A and one B. it should have at least one A and one B. If it doesn't have any of them it shouldn't throw any error...

Comment: Also, "I solved it something like this" almost makes your question off-topic. This site is about reviewing real-life code, not hypothetic code. It's better to post the _complete_ code you wrote, including any `class` declarations and `import` directives.

Comment: ok, I'll post the complete code in some minutes

Comment: What about `[A, A, B]`? It contains both A and B, but their counts are not equal.

Comment: Was this part of a programming challenge of sorts? Since this doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: No, I'm really using this, and the one who is doing the code review is quite pretentious. I isolated the code with a small example, of course.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to ask <List>.contains('A') and <List>.contains('B') and comparing said booleans results to be true ?

Comment: `letters.containsAll(Set.of("A", "B"))` works and will have performance comparable to the other solutions here

Comment: was about to point to containsAll too @JoeLee-Moyet after looking at the List docu at oracle

but I guess he is scared if they occur more than once in the list which means an error too

Comment: Hmm, looking again, it looks like the desired logic is `letters.contains("A") == letters.contains("B")` (which is basically what you said above!)

Comment: Well, @AJNeufeld solution with the two allOrNone methods is the best fit for me. Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Why does `[M, S, C]` works in your example?

Comment: Because has none of A and B. I'm using this to test if I configured both A and B for some filtering into an XML. A and B are in fact two attributes, let's say you cannot configure Name without Surname, but you can configure Address or other available attributes. As I have separate Name and Surname, I have to check that both are configured for my filter to work properly.

Comment: @WDrgn: I would suggest that you add all the relevant information to your question itself, with an [edit]. The question can be reopened if it *clear* and has *sufficient context.*

Comment: well, but I have my answer (marked as the accepted one). Thank you very much for all the answers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you searching for letters (`'A'` and `'B'`) or strings (`"A"` and `"B"`)?  You title says "pair of Strings in a List", but your code's variables are `letter` and `letters`.

---

You have hard-coded the search for the strings `"A"` and `"B"`.  Are these the only two you will look for?  Might you want to search for `"C"` and `"D"`?  Is the condition "all" or "none", in which case, you could also test for all or none of `"X"`, `"Y"` and `"Z"`!

---

You have no early termination.  If you have 1,000,000,000 entries in the list, and both `"A"` and `"B"` are found in the first dozen entries, your `for (String letter : letters)` loop will still continue to the bitter end of the list.  This is wasting time.

You could break out of the loop if, when one of the letters is found it is determined the other has already been found:

```
    for (String letter : letters) {
        if (letter.equals("A")) {
            iA = 1;
            if (iB == 1)
                break;
        } else if (letter.equals("B")) {
            iB = 1;
            if (iA == 1)
                break;
        }
    }
```

---

Here is an "Elegant"(?) stream solution for an "all" or "none" search in a list of strings for a given search set of two or more strings:

```
public static boolean allOrNone(Collection<String> strings, String... search_set) {
    return allOrNone(strings, new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(search_set)));
}

public static boolean allOrNone(Collection<String> strings, Set<String> search_set) {
    long all = search_set.size();
    long occurrences = strings.stream().filter(search_set::contains)
                                       .distinct()
                                       .limit(all)
                                       .count();
    return occurrences == 0 || occurrences == all;
}
```

Notes:

- The `.filter(search_set::contains)` stage will only pass on `strings` which are in the `search_set` to the next stage of the pipeline.
- The `.distinct()` stage will prevent duplicates from continuing down the pipeline.
- The `.limit(all)` stage allows for early termination of the stream.  If `search_set` contains 2 items, when 2 items have made it past the `filter` & `distinct` stages, we must have encountered all of the search items.
- The `.count()` totals the number of strings which made it through all stages of the pipeline ... the unique strings found in the search set.

Answer (score 12):

`iA` and `iB` can only take the values `0` and `1`, so that

```
if ((1 == iA || 1 == iB) && (1 != iA || 1 != iB)) { ... }
```

can be simplified to

```
if (iA != iB) { ... }
```

Boolean variables would be more appropriate for this purpose, and the variable names can be improved, e.g.

```
boolean containsA = false;
boolean containsB = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

I have some suggestions for you.

1. Instead of using list, I suggest that you use [`varargs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html); this will remove the need to put the item in list and pass them to the method.
2. Instead of using `String`, you can use the `Character` to reduce, by a bit, the memory footprint.
3. In the `for` loop, I highly suggest that you use the `if-else-if` pattern or a `switch` instead of the `if-if` since you can only have one choice each time.

**Before**

```java
for (char letter : letters) {
   if (letter == 'A') {
      iA = 1;
   }
   if (letter == 'B') {
      iB = 1;
   }
}
```

**After**

```java
for (char letter : letters) {
   if (letter == 'A') {
      iA = 1;
   } else if (letter == 'B') {
      iB = 1;
   }
}
```

*or*

```java
for (char letter : letters) {
   switch (letter) {
   case 'A':
      iA = 1;
      break;
   case 'B':
      iB = 1;
      break;
   }
}
```

4. When printing arrays, you can use the `java.util.Arrays#toString` method.

#### Refactored Code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
   checkForABPair('B', 'A', 'C');
   checkForABPair('A', 'A', 'C');
   checkForABPair('M', 'S', 'C');
}

public static void checkForABPair(char... letters) {
   int iA = 0;
   int iB = 0;

   for (char letter : letters) {
      switch (letter) {
      case 'A':
         iA = 1;
         break;
      case 'B':
         iB = 1;
         break;
      }
   }

   if ((1 == iA || 1 == iB) && (1 != iA || 1 != iB)) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters) + " - ERROR! The pair of letters [A - B] must be present at least once, or not at all!");
   } else {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(letters) + " - Everything fine!");
   }
}
```